# Multithreading search in an XML file

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am searching an xml file, but this file has 500 items, I want to use threads and assign a thread for each 50 consecutive indexes when the button is clicked. How can I do that? Here is the search code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XmlReader xmlFile;
            xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("Product.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataView dv;
            ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);

            dv = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);
            dv.Sort = "Product_Name";
            int index = dv.Find("Product " + textBox1.Text.ToString());

            if (index == -1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Item Not Found");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(dv[index]["Product_Name"].ToString() + " " + dv[index]["Product_Price"].ToString());
            }
        }
```

This is an item entered in the xml file

```
<Product>
<Product_id>1</Product_id>
<Product_name>Product 1</Product_name>
<Product_price>1000</Product_price>
</Product>
```

Comment: Is it a practical or educational task? It really does not worth it if what you have is that tiny structure.

Comment: it is an educational task, I do know that it is not worth it but I have to get it done and I've searched and haven't found an answer @zerkms

Comment: What are the constraints? Time? Memory? Usage of specific class/method? Multithreading is obligatory?

Comment: time @Mars and multithreading is obligatory yes

Comment: It would be faster with single thread. Those assignments...
1. Select nodes as seen here: http://www.csharp-examples.net/xml-nodes-by-name/ 2. Cast to some collection. 3. Split it every 50th element. 4. Pass each to new thread to process. 5. Gather output and print appropriate message. | Those are relatively easy and "atomic" tasks. You should be able to find answers on how to perform them.

Answer (score 0):

I think we need to parse an XML file in order to have a collection of objects, then used the power of the LINK for searching.

```
class Program
{
    public delegate bool ProcuctComparator(Product elem,string Uservalue);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UsingXml op = new UsingXml();
        string Uservalue = "Product 1";
        ProcuctComparator delg = new ProcuctComparator(byProductName);

        op.parseXml(@"c:\temp\data.xml");

        var elem = op.myProducts.Products.AsParallel().Where(f =>
          {
              return delg(f, Uservalue);
          }).Count();
        Console.WriteLine(elem);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    private static bool byProductName(Product elem, string Uservalue)
    {
        return elem.Product_name.Equals(Uservalue);
    }               

}
 public class UsingXml
{
    public ProductList myProducts { get; set; }
    public void parseXml(string filePath)
    {
        try
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            XmlSerializer xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ProductList));
            myProducts = (ProductList)xmlSer.Deserialize(fs);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

        }
    }
}
 [XmlRoot("Table")]
public class ProductList
{
    public ProductList() { }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Product")]
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
public class Product
{
    public Product() { }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Product_id")]
    public int Product_id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Product_name")]
    public string Product_name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Product_price")]
    public int Product_price { get; set; }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use LINK to XML to search an item from an XML Document since Link to XML uses functional construction approach

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string UserInput = "someCreteria";
        using (var xmlStream = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\peoples.xml", FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (var xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(xmlStream))
            {
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlReader);
                var result = doc.Descendants().AsParallel().Where(x => x.Value.Equals(UserInput)).FirstOrDefault();
                if (result == null)
                    Console.WriteLine("No item found");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine(result.Value.ToString());
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```